# Cypress - What is the baseURL used for running E2E tests on gitlab ci pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, cypress, gitlab-ci

I have written my first E2E tests with Cypress, and so far I am using this cypress.json file:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost/",
    "video": false
}
```

Now, I want to run my E2E tests on Gitlab CI pipeline. What baseURL I use? Any help?

Comment: What have you tried and with what result? Your application has to be deployed somewhere so it can load in a browser. That can very well be localhost even in a pipeline.

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about how your job is setup and how your runners are configured if you're using self-hosted runners.

Comment: I don't understand. The E2E need my changes to be deployed? My idea is to run the test, and if it pass, run the deploy to the homologation environment. Is it not possible?

Comment: @churros it should work. I have my e2e testing setup in GitHub actions & it's working fine. Make sure to run `npm start` before running the `cypress open`.